# HABTM join table name

Tags: cakephp

In case of `Recipe HABTM Ingredient` relation, `name` of `join` is `ingredients_recipes`.

**Is there any CakePHP method or function that return `the name of joinTable between two models`?**

At present I defined a method on AppModel as-

```
public function habtmJoinTableName($model){
    $currentModel = Inflector::tableize($this->name);
    $joinModel = Inflector::tableize($model);

    $joinTable = array($currentModel, $joinModel);
    sort($joinTable);
    return join('_', $joinTable);
}
```

If you don't understand my question please comments. I will try my best to make it clear with my little English knowledge..

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are asking for... maybe if you show your actual code.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in method that would simply return the join table name for two HABTM associated models, no.

CakePHP generates the table name in a method that fills the association configuration with default values, that is [**`Model::_generateAssociation()`**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.5.3/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php#L1104-L1108).

```
// ...

case 'joinTable':
    $tables = array($this->table, $this->{$class}->table);
    sort($tables);
    $data = $tables[0] . '_' . $tables[1];
    break;

// ...
```

As you can see it's doing it pretty much the same way as you are, except for that it is using string concatenation (which is faster), and the `Model::$table` property instead of `Model::$name`, which might not return the results that you'd expect.

So except for that small possible problem with the `name` property that you should change to using `table`, your code should be fine and return the proper table name.